# How to remove webapp folder navigation address from url bar, in php server?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, navigationbar

Like in apache tomcat,
I want to remove folder navigations from url bar.
I have this directory structure in my php server (xampp)

```
localhost/allsites/site1/public/index.php
```

I want to access the same url by just with ip

```
localhost
```

So that, I can access all files from `http://localhost/allsites/site1/public/` folder just as `http://localhost`. If any other folders inside public, it will remain same and can be accessed like, `http://localhost/admin`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set this in  httpd-vhosts.conf like below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
 DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/allsites/site1/public/"
 ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
 ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
 CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Note : This file in xampp\apache\conf\extra and yes in document root use your xampp folder path

Comment: Yes, it works. But along with this, we should un-comment the line
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf in etc/httpd.conf

And also make sure, you added the host name in hosts file